# Why need Message Boards Admin Portlet in Liferay

Tags: liferay

Please explain for me why need make the Message Boards Admin Portlet that we can use  tag in Message Boards Portlet to show in Control Panel.
I have read Liferay source code and didn't found any thing different between 2 portlet without view page.

Thank you!

Comment: The view page is what makes up a portlet in the first place. So if they differ you will have to create two different portlets...

Comment: Thank @TobiasLiefke for your comment. I believe they can do that by using check themeDisplay.isControlPanel() instead of build a different portlet. Do you think so?

Comment: For sure: you can integrate different portlets into one big portlets. But that would have no use (see [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns))

Comment: My problem is when my customer want to set a portlet preferences (as mail from) which effects all sites use this portlet. He must execute that in site, not in control panel. So he can not manage messages all in one place (Message Boards Admin) and feel uncomfortable. I can custom that but I not sure view page is only reason to make a different portlet. I am also not clear about why Document and Media portlet or Web Content portlet can set portlet preferences in control panel, but Message Boards can not. So I ask this question.